# Flutter Cart Item not updating if product already available in cart & not saving in database for

Tags: flutter

I have created Shopping cart for ecommerce app. I am able to add new item to cart with quantity 1, but other condition of If where item is already in cart, quantity is not increasing by + 1. I am not getting any error as well in console.

Also, How do i save this in local database. whenever i refresh app, cart items becomes 0.

```
class CartItemStored with ChangeNotifier {
     Map<String, Product> _newitemList= {};

     Map<String, Product> get newItemList{
       return{..._newitemList};
     }

     List<Product> _list =[];
     List<Product> get list{
       return[..._list];
     }

  int get itemListCount {
    return newItemList.length;
  }

     double get totalAmount {
       var total = 0.0;
       _newitemList.forEach((key, cartItem) {
         total += cartItem.productListPrice  * cartItem.quantity;
       });
       return total;
     }

  void addtoCart(
    int productId,
    String productName,
    int productListPrice,
    int productSalePrice,
    String productSku,
    int quantity,
  ) {
    if (_newitemList.containsKey(productId)){
      _newitemList.update(productId.toString(), (existingCartItem) => Product(
        productId: productId,
        productName: productName,
        productListPrice: productListPrice,
        productSalePrice: productSalePrice,
        productSku: productSku,
        quantity: quantity + 1,
      ));
    } else{
      _newitemList.putIfAbsent(productId.toString(), ()=> Product(
        productId: productId,
        productName: productName,
        productListPrice: productListPrice,
        productSalePrice: productSalePrice,
        productSku: productSku,
        quantity: 1,
      ));

    }notifyListeners();
    DBHelper.insert('cart', {
      'productId': productId,
      'productName': productName,
      'productListPrice': productListPrice,
      'productSalePrice': productSalePrice,
      'productSku': productSku,
      'quantity': quantity,
    });

  }

  Future<void> fetchAndSetCart() async {
    final dataList = await DBHelper.getCartData('cart');
    _newitemList = dataList.map((itemList) => Product(
      productId: itemList['productId'],
      productName: itemList['productName'],
      productSalePrice: itemList['productSalePrice'],
      productListPrice: itemList['productListPrice'],
      productSku: itemList['productSku'],
      quantity: itemList['quantity'],

    )) as Map<String, Product>;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

```
class DBHelper {
  static Future<Database> database() async {
    final dbPath = await sql.getDatabasesPath();
    return sql.openDatabase(path.join(dbPath, 'cart.db'),
        onCreate: (db, version) {
      db.execute(
          'CREATE TABLE cart(productId TEXT, productName TEXT,productListPrice TEXT,productSalePrice TEXT,productSku TEXT,quantity TEXT)');
    }, version: 1);
  }

  static Future<void> insert(String table, Map<String, Object> data) async {
    final db = await DBHelper.database();
    db.insert(table, data, conflictAlgorithm: sql.ConflictAlgorithm.replace);
  }

  static Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getCartData(String table) async {
    final db = await DBHelper.database();
    return db.query(table);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you should use Shared Preferences to save data. Here is the package :[package](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences)

Comment: I am looking to store Cart data only in local storage so Sqflite is fine for that.. I am not sure what i am doing wrong as after app is refreshed, data doesn't show.. i need to fix that

Comment: I am sorry for that but I can't help you with that:Just I am using shared preferences to save string and int. It sounds stupid but maybe you can save the count of cart items with shared preferences as int and add a for loop to add items as much as saved in shared preferences, also you can save the items name with shared preferences as string.